# Route not define exception with laravel route::controller

Tags: php, laravel, exception

i have route like this :

```
Route::controller('/users', 'AdminUsersController', array(
    "revokeUser" => "admin.user.revoke_user",
));
```

and this is my controller

```
public function revokeUser($nationalCode)
{
 dd("I'm in");

}
```

but when im going to use route i have exception route not defined

```
    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{{ URL::route('admin.user.revoke_user',array($user->national_code)) }}">
 Click here 
</a>
```

exception :

> Route [admin.user.revoke_user] not defined. (View:
>   /var/www/pedram.dev/blog/app/views/admin/users/index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in routes.php

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/users/{nationalCode}', ['as' => 'admin.user.revoke_user', 'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@revokeUser']);
```

EDIT you are getting error because your function takes argument and in your route definition you haven't defined argument. So you need :

```
Route::controller('/users/{nationalCode}', 'AdminUsersController', array(
    "revokeUser" => "admin.user.revoke_user",
));
```

Comment: i know that,thanks but i have to know what's problem in my code.